# How to raise the notification level of timeline updates?

Tags: google-mirror-api

Are there options other than `DEFAULT` for the notification level?`timelineItem.setNotification(new NotificationConfig().setLevel("DEFAULT"));`

I would like the screen to turn on to show my new/updated card instead of just hearing the sound and having to quickly turn the glass on to catch the notification or have to scroll through to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are only two notification levels: [`DEFAULT`](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/insert) and [`NULL`](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-counter-sample-python/blob/master/notify/handler.py).

The Glass team has decided against allowing developers to use the Mirror API to automatically turn on screens. There was a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=74&can=1&q=on%20status=WontFix&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary) that the team closed. Here is the explanation:

> This is something that we've considered, but as it turns out, it's really distracting. We're continuing to experiment with ways to make notifications rich, but bringing the screen on automatically is probably not something that we'll ever provide in the Mirror API.

Comment: What does setting the notification level to `NULL` do compared to `DEFAULT`?